# Qt Widgets, is it mandatory to set the containing widget as parent?

Tags: c++, qt, widget, qt5

I would like to insert a QWidget inside a container QWidget (via its layout), but avoid parenting the inserted widget to the container widget.

There are good reasons behind this, the inserted widget is a toolbox tied to a document, and this toolbox is sent to a floating dock widget when the document becomes the active document.

Is this possible?

Answer (score 1):

> I would like to insert a QWidget inside a container QWidget (via its
>   layout), but avoid parenting the inserted widget to the container
>   widget.
>
> There are good reasons behind this, the inserted widget is a toolbox
>   tied to a document, and this toolbox is sent to a floating dock widget
>   when the document becomes the active document.
>
> Is this possible?

This simple answer is No - cannot avoid the widget being parented. But hold on. First, why the answer is No. Then how can we still do what you want.

Setting the layout for the widget does an implicit parent set.
Setting the widget for the layout does an implicit parent set.

```
QVBoxLayout* layout = new QVBoxLayout; // no parent yet
this->setLayout(layout);               // it does layout->setParent(this);
QWidget* widget = new MyWidget;        // no parent yet
layout->addWidget( widget );           // it does widget->setParent(this);
```

> If layout is the layout manager on a different widget, setLayout()
>   will reparent the layout and make it the layout manager for this
>   widget.

With QLayout the reparenting is a bit more complicated because addWidget does call addItem:

> void QLayout::addItem(QLayoutItem * item)
>
> Implemented in subclasses to add an item. How it is added is specific
>   to each subclass.
>
> This function is not usually called in application code. To add a
>   widget to a layout, use the addWidget() function; to add a child
>   layout, use the addLayout() function provided by the relevant QLayout
>   subclass.
>
> Note: The ownership of item is transferred to the layout, and it's the
>   layout's responsibility to delete it.
>
> See also addWidget(), QBoxLayout::addLayout(), and
>   QGridLayout::addLayout().
>
> void QLayout::addWidget(QWidget * w)
>
> Adds widget w to this layout in a manner specific to the layout. This
>   function uses addItem().

But we can still do something about such request:

> There are good reasons behind this, the inserted widget is a toolbox
>   tied to a document, and this toolbox is sent to a floating dock widget
>   when the document becomes the active document.
>
> Is this possible?

But that is of course possible. Say, by calling [QWidget::setParent](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qwidget.html#setParent) which is quite a common practice when we need to move the parent into new layout.